# Offset left or right of the tooltip chartsjs

Tags: chart.js

I have issue with custom position tooltip's. 
I can not make a custom anyone can help me with some tip ?
how can I make the tooltip get further away from the point ??

```
 //Individual chart config
var ctx = "myChart";
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'lala',
    },
    layout: {
      padding: 32
    },
    tooltips: {

      position: 'custom'
    },
  },
  data: {
    labels: ['0%', '10%', '20%', '30%', '40%', '50%'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'one',
      data: [44, 44, 55, 16, 33, 45],
      borderColor: '#ab045',
      backgroundColor: 'RGBA(33, 55, 167, .1)',
      pointBorderColor: "#4ad1C0",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
      pointHitRadius: 10
    }, {
      label: 'two',
      data: [82, 12, 24, 30, 2, 5],
      borderColor: '#34315a',
      backgroundColor: 'RGBA(33, 23, 124, .7)',
      pointBorderColor: "#34495e",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
      pointHitRadius: 10
    }]
  }
});
```

My [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cide10/fpqvkta2/10/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New modes can be defined by adding functions to the Chart.Tooltip.positioners map ([DOC](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#position-modes)). This function returns the x and y position for the tooltip.

You can add a custom one to adjust the x at an offset

```
 //register custome positioner
Chart.Tooltip.positioners.custom = function(elements, position) {
    if (!elements.length) {
      return false;
    }
    var offset = 0;
    //adjust the offset left or right depending on the event position
    if (elements[0]._chart.width / 2 > position.x) {
      offset = 20;
    } else {
      offset = -20;
    }
    return {
      x: position.x + offset,
      y: position.y
    }
  }
```

Do not forget set your custom function into your options when rendering your chart

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/edicarlos10/zo4qamwx/1/) example working

Comment: Works like charm!! Thx!